# Does Ruby support verbatim strings?

Tags: ruby, string, syntax

Is there support in Ruby for (for lack of a better word) non-escaped (verbatim) strings?

Like in C#:

```
@"c:\Program Files\"
```

...or in Tcl:

```
{c:\Program Files\}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to prefix your string with `%` and then a single character delineating its type.

The one you want is `%q{c:\program files\}`.

The pickaxe book covers this nicely [here,](http://www.rubycentral.org/pickaxe/language.html) section is General Delimited Input.

Comment: why not just use single quotes?

Comment: typically because you need quotes as apostrophes or multiple quotes, or unbalanced quotes in your string.

Comment: Just updating the link the the pickaxe book as .com seems to be gone now.

http://www.rubycentral.org/pickaxe/language.html

Comment: @banister: Single quotes work, but only if you're willing to escape all those backslashes with more backslashes, which can get ugly in cases such as Windows file paths. For obvious reasons, leaving it as `'c:\program files\'` will not work as intended.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a single quoted string.

```
>> puts "a\tb"
a    b
=> nil
>> puts 'a\tb'
a\tb
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides %q{string}, you can also do the following:

```
string =<<SQL
  SELECT * 
  FROM Book
  WHERE price > 100.00
  ORDER BY title;
SQL
```

The delimiters are arbitrary strings, conventionally in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = %q["'\t blahblahblah]
```

Or if you want to interpret `\t` as tab:

```
mystring = %Q["'\t blahblahblah]
```